# Tooltip Converter run on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I need tooltip to retrieve some slow data on demand

```
ToolTip="{Binding FullPath, Converter={StaticResource SlowConverter}, IsAsync=True}"
```

It takes up to a second for my converter to retrieve data from FullPath and I do not want it to do it unless user hovers the element (ListBoxItem) to get the ToolTip. I expected the Tooltip to resolve binding on MouseOver but it does it as soon as item is visible.

Is there a way the converter to execute only on mouse over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using a trigger like so :

```
 <Button Content="oK" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding FullPath,Converter={StaticResource SlowConverter}}" ></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>            
    </Button>
```

i assumed here that your tooltip is inside a button.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you! The only thing I had to change is `IsAsync=False` because otherwise the tooltip would not be shown occasionally even though converter resolves value.